# How to save the R output in different directory?

Tags: r, directory, save, output

I have three different folders name as  "5k", "10k" and "15k", I can save the  `R` out from the following code using this for loop.

```
iter_no=c(5000,10000,15000)
    iter_name=c("5k","10k","15k")
    for ( i in 1:length(iter_no)){
      y=rnorm(iter_no[i])
      setwd(paste0("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/prac_fol/",iter_name[i]))
      save(y,  file =paste0("ydat",iter_name[i],".RData"))
    }
```

Is there any shortcut or better way to do this.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of switching the working dir with setwd you can use file.path, e.g. `file = file.path("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/prac_fol", iter_name[i],paste0("ydat",iter_name[i],".RData"))`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It looks like you are omitting `/` in the second call to `paste0`.

```
iter_no=c(5000,10000,15000)
iter_name=c("5k","10k","15k")
for ( i in 1:length(iter_no)){
  y=rnorm(iter_no[i])
  file = paste0("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/prac_fol/",iter_name[i], '/' , "ydat",iter_name[i],".RData")
  save(y,  file = file)
}
```